# slow alpha blending opengl es 1.1

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I have looked over quite a few forums, but have been unable to increase the fps on ipad retina. I currently get 40 fps and am targeting 60.
I am using orthographic projection for my 2d game. I have to draw 1 opaque background, 3 transparent backgrounds, and 20 transparent images(10 of size 1/4 of screen and 10 of 1/10 of screen).
I can draw all small images, and background, but when i draw other transparent backgrounds i get 40 fps.
What all i have done till now:
1) disable blending with opaque objects
2) disable alpha testing
3) decrease bits of images
4) decrease resolution of images

here is my alpha blending code:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Please help!!!!

Comment: It is very slow to draw so much to the retina screens.  I don't think  your code is necessarily at fault.

Comment: Hey I think something is wrong, because i started to notice inconsistent FPS every time i play the game. Drawing the same images i sometimes get 60 and sometimes 40 fps.